# Rotas no goole Mapas

Tags: intel-xdk

Estou criando um aplicativo e gostaria de saber se tem como eu criar dois pontos em um mapa sendo o primeiro minha localização e o segundo ponto minha localização atualizada tipo a maneira que vou me movendo fica A fixo enquanto B vai atualizando o trajeto e me mostrando a rota é possivel fazer isso ? E como fazer?

Answer (score 0):

Tem como fazer sim, mas para isso você precisa dar uma estudada na API do Google Maps

Segue 2 links que considero muito bom para iniciar:
http://www.thiengo.com.br/obtendo-e-apresentando-rotas-no-google-maps-android-v2
http://blog.caelum.com.br/usando-o-google-maps-e-gps-no-android/

e o link da API
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/?hl=pt-br